# Tracking down disk space usage on a machine with docker network volumes

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nfs, ubuntu-16.04, disk-space-utilization

I have an Ubuntu server 16.04 VM running my docker containers. It has a relatively small disk (~60GB) which I thought would be fine because I have dedicated NFS storage that I mount via docker to the services that need it.

The server's disk is very full but I cannot track down what's causing it because all the methods I normally use for finding large disk usage (`ncdu`, `du -sh *`) are counting the size of the *remote* storage as well. (i.e. they say I'm using 13TB/60GB).

How can I figure out how much *actual, physical, local* disk is being used my each directory?

Comment: *du -x* will ignore directories on the different file systems

Comment: YES! That's exactly what I needed. Please repeat in an answer so I can give you karma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell disk usage tools not to cross file system boundaries. For example with  *-x* option for *du*.

```
du -shx *
```